# Java Util Logger (WAS v7) - Concurrency issue

Tags: logging, concurrency, java.util.logging

I am currently using Java Util Loggers integrated with WAS v7. We have a custom singleton Logger class ..

public class CustomLogger {

```
private Logger logger = null;
```

..
..
    private CustomLogger() {
        super();
    }
.
.
// Method which returns the logger instance, which is called from other application projects,

```
public static CustomLogger getCustomLogger(String loggerName) {
    CustomLogger customLogger = new CustomLogger();
    // check if logger name is null
    if (loggerName == null || loggerName.isEmpty())
        loggerName = DEFAULT_LOGGER_NM;
    // check if logger already exist in log manager.
    LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    try {
        logManager.readConfiguration(readURLReference(LOGGING_PROPERTIES_URL_JNDI));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger loggerLocal = logManager.getLogger(loggerName);
    if (loggerLocal == null) {
        loggerLocal = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);

    }
    configure(loggerLocal);
    loadProperties(readURLReference(LOGGING_PROPERTIES_URL_JNDI));

    for (Handler tempHandler : loggerLocal.getHandlers()) {
        tempHandler.flush();
        tempHandler.close();
        loggerLocal.removeHandler(tempHandler);
    }
    customLogger.setLogger(loggerLocal);
    return customLogger;
}
```

I load the property file from the URL reference in the WAS.

The places which consume the loggers,

private final CustomLogger logger = CustomLogger.getCustomLogger(className);

---

The problem,

When i give parallel request to 2 different services present at 2 different EARs at the same time, the application Logs which we write gets mixed up. Did anybody face similar issues or have any idea on how to resolve?

Thanks,
Siva